In the tunneling effect, to find a particle inside the barrier must I necessarily supply energy to the particle?
In the tunneling effect a particle with energy $E_1$ can pass through a thin barrier of height $V_0$ even if $E_1<V_0$.
Since the wave function inside the barrier is not zero, then it is possible to find the particle inside the barrier.
Let's assume that we have performed a measurement operation that finds the particle inside the barrier.
The measurement causes the collapse of the wave function. The new wave function is zero outside the barrier.
Since the new wave function is in a region with potential energy $V_0$, the total energy $E_2$ (potential plus kinetic) associated with the state must be equal to or greater than the potential energy $V_0$, so now the total energy of the particle $E_2$ is greater than the initial value $E_1$. It turns out $E_2\geq V_0>E_1$.
So to find the particle in the barrier must my measurement operation necessarily supply energy?

Any observation that strongly localizes the position, such as hitting it with a very short-wavelength photon, will tend to give the particle a lot of energy.


Since the new wave function is in a region with potential energy $V_0$, the total energy $E_2$ (potential plus kinetic) associated with the state must be equal to or greater than the potential energy $V_0$, so now the total energy of the particle $E_2$ is greater than the initial value $E_1$. It turns out $E_2\geq V_0>E_1$.

(emphasis is mine)
Let me start with a remark, that potential plus kinetic is classical definition of the total energy, which does not work in QM, since the kinetic and the potential energies do not commute,
$$
[K,V]\neq 0.$$ At best, this statement can be applied to the mean values of the three energies
$$
\langle E\rangle = \langle K\rangle + \langle V\rangle$$
From the quantum mechanical point of view we start with a wave function, which is a scattering eigenstate of Hamiltonian:
$$
H=K+V(x), H\psi(x)=E\psi(x),\\
\psi(x)=\begin{cases}e^{+ikx}+Re^{-ikx}, x\rightarrow -\infty\\
Te^{ikx}, x\rightarrow +\infty\end{cases}
$$
where typically $K=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ (although different kinetic terms are possible, especially in solid state theory.) The potential contains a barrier, with a region where $V(x)\geq E$, which we delimit as $\left[-\frac{\Delta}{2},\frac{\Delta}{2}\right]$.
We now perform a measurement, by projecting the state on eigenstates of a different Hamiltonian, which are very close to position eigenstates, or at least strongly localized in the barrier region. In other words, we perturb the system and find it in an eigenstate of a different Hamiltonian:
$$
H_1=K+V(x)+U(x)
$$
For simplicity one could treat $U(x)$ as a infinite potential well, so that the state in which electron finds itself is an eigenstate in an infinite potential well with with the bottom energy $V(0)$, so that its eigenenergies are
$$E_n= V(0)+\frac{n^2h^2}{8m\Delta^2}$$ or something like that. They are above the barrier energy by construction - it couldn't be otherwise.
Without the assumption of a rectangular barrier we can use the uncertainty relation:
$$\delta p \Delta\geq \hbar/2\Rightarrow \langle K\rangle = \frac{\hbar^2}{8m\Delta^2},$$
whereas the potential energy is still bounded from below by the height of the barrier, that is
$$E> \frac{\hbar^2}{8m\Delta^2} + V(0).$$
Remark
In the discussion above I assume that the barrier still exists after the measurement - of course, if the measurement is such as to destroy or compensate of the barrier, nothing prevents electron from having energy below $V(0)$.

Many thanks Roger for your rigorous and clear answer.
You demonstrate that, following the measurement operation and the relative collapse of the wave function, the particle has an average energy that is greater than the one the particle had before the measurement.
Furthermore, from the calculation you demonstrate that the energy is greater than the height of the barrier.
So is it correct to conclude that the measurement operation necessarily provided energy to the particle?

@GiovanniMastrogiovanni Yes, I believe this is the correct conclusion. In hand-waving manner one could say that we need energy to confine the particle to a narrow region of space.


So to find the particle in the barrier must my measurement operation necessarily supply energy?

No, because we know examples of quantum tunneling which have nothing to do with measurement in the sense of quantum theory, that is, with finding out result of measurement and updating the quantum state to make it consistent with that result.
These examples are e.g. tunnel diode, alpha decay, and nuclear fusion.
Quantum tunneling is believed to take place in these based on indirect evidence, because of some other phenomena which are hard to explain without it - too large electric current, observing too many alpha particles, or effects of nuclear reaction (lots of radiation produced).
If we ask where the energy for tunneling comes from in those cases, we implicitly assume conservation of energy holds. If we assume conservation holds at all times, we are forced to assume the system has definite energy at all times. But that is not how quantum theory works. Quantum systems can be in quantum states in which energy is not defined. Thus in between measurements, if the system gets into a state that is not an energy eigenstate, we are forced to abandon this view of conservation of energy.
We can still have a kind of conservation of energy in quantum theory - when comparing energy values corresponding to eigenstates. If an isolated system evolves from initial energy eigenstate to another energy eigenstate, then the associated energy has to be the same. If we start with a state that is a superposition of two energy eigenstates, then only the expectation value of energy is conserved in time. If after some evolution happens, we try to measure, in the sense of quantum theoretical measurement, energy on such system somehow (I don't know how), we have to interact with the system, and then we may get a definite value of energy that may be different from that expectation value, so naive conservation does not hold.
It is tempting to try to save conservation of energy when comparing energy before and after measurement, by supposing the necessary energy difference was extracted or supplied by the environment(which includes the measurement device), but this idea requires that energy of all interacting subsystems is defined both before and after measurement, including that of the environment. But I do not know how to motivate such an assumption, it goes against the fact that interaction produces superpositions.
So the only obviously valid and conceptually clear conservation of energy here is conservation of expectation value of the energy operator. The actual results of energy measurements, if we can get them somehow, do not seem to obey any such theorem, because they are to some extent random, and I do not see a good independent reason to assume random changes of the measured system energy are compensated by exactly opposite changes of energy of the environment.
In contrast to classical theory (including particles and fields, e.g. EM fields), in quantum theory, we have states where even if energy of the whole isolated supersystem is defined, energies of the subsystems (measured system),(measurement device), (rest), are not defined.
